# RewriteRule in htaccess having no affect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Sorry, this is probably a simple issue but I've read tons of tutorials and can't solve the issue.  Here's the URL sample:

http://localhost:8106/privacy-policy/?lang=fr&dest=app

The .htaccess contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/?lang=([a-z][a-z])&dest=app$    privacy-policy/$1   [NC,L]
```

When I visit the URL I don't get redirected. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in a rule, you need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z][a-z])&dest=app$
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/$    privacy-policy/%1   [NC,L]
```

Note that the backreference needs to be `%1`. If you need it to redirect the browser, you'll also need a `R` flag in the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon Lin for the leads on the query_string and %1 edit. It didn't end up working with a copy/paste of that code but this is finally what I ended up with and it is working:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} privacy-policy 
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(\w+)&dest=app 
  RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/$ /privacy-policy/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Thanks again for your help on this.